# Blender won't finish rendering

Tags: rendering

When i try to make my intro, my blender keeps on rendering and then when it's done, it starts all over repeatedly. I waited a while and it keeps on doing the same thing for like an hour.

Comment: it looks like you're rendereing an animation, try rendering a single image/frame (F12 or render menu->render image)

Answer (score 5):

As said by [Bithur](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/11431/bithur) in the comments, it is quite possible that you are rendering an animation. Stop the current render with the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key. Then press <kbd>F12</kbd> (make sure that you don't press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> by accident!), or go to `Render` -> `Render Image` from the toolbar.

[image: Toolbar (image)]

If it continues to do the same, go into the render settings and make sure that `Sampled motion blur` is **un**checked. If even this doesn't help make the render finish, uncheck `Anti-Aliasing` (I am not really sure this will help, but you can try...).

[image: Annotations (image)]

Comment: Is there any chance this answer getting accepted?